# Telerik GridView Datetime Column set to "" based on condition

Tags: c#, gridview, telerik

I have a default value for `datetime` column in GridView which is `1/1/1900`

what I want if the value is `1/1/1900` I want the cell to be blank.

I am really new in this environment so bear with me.

here's my code:

```
    void SetDate()
    {
        GridViewDateTimeColumn ExpiryDate = this.gvItemReceiptDetails.Columns["ExpiryDate"] as GridViewDateTimeColumn;
        ExpiryDate.FormatString = "{0:M/d/yyyy}";
        ExpiryDate.FormatInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
        ExpiryDate.NullValue = "";

    }
```

[image]

Comment: How about checking the data in `ItemDataBound()` ?

Comment: @un-lucky I'm working on the cell_formatting right now.. uhm can you give me an example sir?

Comment: @un-lucky I've got it already sir.. I just do it on cell_formatting... getting the value of datetime column and check if the value is 1/1/1900..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following using ItemDataBound:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Is it a GridDataItem
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        //Get the instance of the right type
        GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        //Check the formatting condition
        if (dataBoundItem["ExpiryDate"].Text =="1/1/1900")
        {
           dataBoundItem["ExpiryDate"].Text="";
            //Customize more if needed...
        }
    }
}
```